How the SCR junction J2 is reversed biased even though n section of J2 is not connected to any voltage?

I am confused about how the Junction J2 for the connection above can be reverse biased. The book I have only says that the junctions J1 and J2 are in forward biased but does not explain it. I need clarification on how J2 is reversed even though n section of J2 is not connected to any voltage.
I think it would be easier to correct myself if I explain first how I think it works.
Since the leftmost p section is connected to high voltage it draws electrons from the adjacent n type. This drawing of electrons from n type widens the J2 barrier and thus it can be said to be reverse biased.
I am not sure if it is the right explanation.

Your explanation is basically correct.
The left pn portion (forming j1) is (slightly) forward biased. Therefore the voltage on the n portion is about 0.7 V lower than the supply voltage (perhaps 0.4 V; very little current actually flows until the SCR is triggered; the voltage is defined by leakages and hard-to-guess approximations).
If no trigger V is applied, j3 is also forward biased in the same way.
Typically an SCR will have resistor (or resistances or similar) across these junctions to actually make the V much closer to zero (because j2 is reverse biased, and actually very little current flows).
When a V is applied to j3, it acts as the B-E of an NPN. Holes are injected to the right (n), and carry current to the n contact. Simultaneously electrons are injected from R to L. These diffuse 'up' to j2 where they are 'collected' by that n. This does cause a current to flow in the j2 pn junction, which similarly injects electrons to the left and holes to the right; these holes arrive at j2's p whereupon they cause j3's forward bias to increase.
These currents generate positive feedback, leading to larger and larger currents flowing through the whole structure. Current builds up until I*R drops and losses limit it -- this happens at about 1 V across the whole structure.
Basically, it is forming an NPN and PNP closely interconnected.

That actually helped. I have a follow up question.  Since p of J2 acts much like the base of an NPN transistor, that p has to have smaller width, right?

Yes, but you usually don't need or want particularly high beta. In fact you usually prefer low beta and good, low base resistance
